# How to use $().ajaxSend in iframe context

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node-webkit

I have a page with an `<iframe>`. With every ajax request from page inside `<iframe>` I want to execute a function. `$().ajaxSend` seems right option.

But is there a way to define it for `<iframe>` context like instead of `$(document)` something like `$("iframe")`?

Comment: The global jQuery Ajax Events are ... well global, they fire when any ajax call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is javascript code to access document inside iframe from parent

```
    var iframe_Doc = document.getElementById('iframeID');
    iframe_Doc = iframe_Doc .contentDocument || iframe_Doc .contentWindow.document;

    //this code will be called from Parent    
    $( iframe_Doc ).ajaxSend(function() {
       //your call
    });
```

Comment: This is giving the warning of ' HTMLHeadElement.profile is deprecated. The reflected attribute has no effect'.